# How to set two panels in east of frame

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

Like this,

[image]

How to set two panels in east of frame and maintain fixed size of panel one and two?

How to set image BG of frame?

Answer (score 2):

By nested layouts. Add a [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) on the `EAST` of your [`BoarderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html). See *Andrew Thompson* answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621338/how-to-add-jtable-in-jpanel).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a bit of manual tinkering you can use the SpringLayout to take manual control of layouts.  Using this approach I have made a little mock-up based on your picture.  Have a look and see if it can help.  If you use the commented out line as well  (replacing the line above it) it should keep the sizes the same

```
public class SO{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setBackground(java.awt.Color.RED);

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JButton but1 = new JButton("Button 1");
    JButton but2 = new JButton("Button 2");
    panel2.setBackground(java.awt.Color.BLUE);
    panel2.add(but1);
    panel2.add(but2);

    SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
    frame.setLayout(layout);

    frame.add(panel1);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, panel1, -5, SpringLayout.EAST, frame.getContentPane());
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, panel1, -200, SpringLayout.EAST, frame.getContentPane());
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, panel1, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, frame.getContentPane());
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, panel1, -5, SpringLayout.NORTH, panel2);
    //layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, panel1, 200, SpringLayout.NORTH, frame.getContentPane()); swap this for the above one to keep the sizes the same

    frame.add(panel2);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, panel2, -5, SpringLayout.EAST, frame.getContentPane());
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, panel2, -200, SpringLayout.EAST, frame.getContentPane());
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, panel2, -100, SpringLayout.SOUTH, frame.getContentPane());
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, panel2, -5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, frame.getContentPane());

    frame.setSize(400, 350);
    frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What you do is:

- Make a new panel (for this example called outerPanel)
- add the 2 panels you want to this outerPanel
- THEN add this outerPanel to the frame